# Pytorch doesn't use all available CUDA devices

Tags: pytorch, gpu, large-language-model

I have a problem and maybe someone from you can help me to solve it. I have two LLMs 7b (I applied to torch 16bit) and I tried to run it on GPU, for this purpose, I used an Azure node with 2 GPU layers NVIDIA A100 16GB each, but after all, I had a CUDA out of memory. I tried to split it into two devices like device_0 = torch.device("cuda:0") and device_1 = torch.device("cuda:1"), also with the help of "os" tried to make CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0,1, put the same script into running command something like CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0,1 python3 my.app, but nothing helps me, will be very grateful if someone will share with me with their experience.
In addition when I use torch.visible_devices it provide to me that cuda can see two of them.

I tried to run two LLMs on one node

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']="0,1"
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["PYTORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA"] = "0,1"

import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()                                                                                                                
device_0= torch.device("cuda:0")
device_1= torch.device("cuda:1")
pipe = pipeline(
"text-generation", 
model=model_1,             l
tokenizer=tokenizer,
device=device_0,
max_new_tokens = 1024,  
temperature=0.3,
repetition_penalty=1.15  )
```

The same think I used for the second pipeline, but only difference I put to device: device_1 and model = model_2

Comment: Please provide your code, how do you use `device_0` and `device_1`? Did you ensure you had the right count *inside* your python script?

Comment: Yes, I first checked the device id and then assigned that to my device variable. And then I applied to LLM device_0 and to another device_1.                device_0= torch.device("cuda:0")
device_1= torch.device("cuda:1").

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: edit your question to include code, not put it as a comment here.